# Accessing response headers using a decorator in Armeria

Tags: armeria

I would like to add a decorator to my armeria client that checks each http response if a certain http header was returned:

```
    builder.decorator((delegate, ctx, req) -> {
      final HttpResponse response = delegate.execute(ctx, req);
      final AggregatedHttpResponse r = response.aggregate().join();
      for (Map.Entry<AsciiString, String> header : r.headers()) {
        if ("warning".equalsIgnoreCase(header.getKey().toString())) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Detected usage of deprecated API for request "
            + req.toString() + ":\n" + header.getValue());
        }
      }
      return response;
    });
```

However, when starting my client it blocks on the `join()` call and waits forever. Is there a standard pattern for this in Armeria ? Presumably i cannot just block on the response in an interceptor, but i could not find a way to access the response headers otherwise. Using `subscribe` or `toDuplicator` did not work any better though.

Comment: Not directly related with the question, but you can just use `ResponseHeaders.contains()` because header names in Armeria are always lower-case.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for this @trustin your below suggestion worked like a charm !

Comment: My pleasure. Let me look forward to more questions from you 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve the desired behavior.

The first option is to aggregate the response asynchronously and then convert it back to an `HttpResponse`. The key APIs are `AggregatedHttpResponse.toHttpResponse()` and `HttpResponse.from(CompletionStage)`:

```java
builder.decorator(delegate, ctx, req) -> {
    final HttpResponse res = delegate.serve(ctx, req);
    return HttpResponse.from(res.aggregate().thenApply(r -> {
        final ResponseHeaders headers = r.headers();
        if (headers...) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        // Convert AggregatedHttpResponse back to HttpResponse.
        return r.toHttpResponse();
    }));
});
```

This approach is fairly simple and straightforward, but it doesn't work for a streaming response, because it waits until the complete response body is ready.

If your service returns a potentially large streaming response, you can use a `FilteredHttpResponse` to filter the response without aggregating anything:

```java
builder.decorator(delegate, ctx, req) -> {
    final HttpResponse res = delegate.serve(ctx, req);
    return new FilteredHttpResponse(res) {
        @Override
        public HttpObject filter(HttpObject obj) {
            // Ignore other objects like HttpData.
            if (!(obj instanceof ResponseHeaders)) {
                return obj;
            }

            final ResponseHeaders headers = (ResponseHeaders) obj;
            if (headers...) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            return obj;
        }
    };
});
```

It's slightly more verbose than the first option, but it does not buffer the response in the memory, which is great for large streaming responses.

Ideally, in the future, we'd like to add more operators to `HttpResponse` or `StreamMessage`. Please stay tuned to this issue page and add any suggestions for better API: https://github.com/line/armeria/issues/3097